# Restricting hours and minutes in DatePicker- swift?

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

hi guys im trying to create a time picker which hours are only from (2pm - 9pm) and minutes are incremented by 30 [this is the picture of timePicker that i want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdrfS.png)
here is my code

```
func creatTimePicker() {
        timePicker.datePickerMode = .time
        timePicker.minuteInterval = 30
        let timeformatter = DateFormatter()
        timeformatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

        let min = timeformatter.date(from: "5:00")
        let max = timeformatter.date(from: "9:00")
        timePicker.minimumDate = min
        timePicker.maximumDate = max
        self.contentView.addSubview(timePicker)
    }
```

the problem is hour starts 1-12 and minute starts 00-59 what is the problem? thank you

Comment: set minimumDate "14:00" and maximumDate "21:00", try this.

Comment: did not work :(

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Calendar` to constraint the time range for UIDatePicker()

```swift
        let picker = UIDatePicker()
        picker.datePickerMode = .time
        
        let minDate = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 14, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) // 2PM
        
        let maxDate = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 21, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) // 9PM
    
        picker.minimumDate = minDate
        picker.maximumDate = maxDate
```

This won't let user select time outside the specified time range.

### In case you want to show only these hours

You can use `UIPickerView`

**Example:**

```swift
let picker = UIPickerView()
picker.dataSource = self
picker.delegate = self

let hoursRange = Array(5...9)

// Data source

func numberOfComponents(in: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        print("Com :\(component)")
        if component == 0 {
            return hoursRange.count
        }
        
        return 1 // For the PM indicator
    }

// Delegate
    
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
     titleForRow row: Int,
     forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        switch component {
        case 0:
            return "\(hoursRange[row])"
        case 1:
            return "AM"
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help the only thing that im considering now is the range of hours to show only 5-9. the functions above are just enables hours 5-9 but still showing 1-12 !! ?

Comment: You would have to create `UIPickerView` with component's rows that you manually add from 5-9. Otherwise, you can't hide them in `UIDatePicker`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to set the date picker date property to match the minimum date as well. You need also to set the date formatter default date to today and don't forget to set the locale to "en_US_POSIX" when parsing your date string time:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let time: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = .init(identifier: "em_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

---

```
let timePicker = UIDatePicker()
func creatTimePicker() {
    Formatter.time.defaultDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
    let minimumDate = Formatter.time.date(from: "14:00")!
    let maximumDate = Formatter.time.date(from: "21:00")!
    timePicker.date = minimumDate 
    timePicker.datePickerMode = .time
    timePicker.minuteInterval = 30
    timePicker.minimumDate = minimumDate
    timePicker.maximumDate = maximumDate
    self.contentView.addSubview(timePicker)
}
```

Comment: thank you Leo for your help but how i can show ONLY hours from 5-9 ??

Comment: What do you mean? `minuteInterval = 60` and change the `minimumDate` and `maximumDate`